# Como corrigir esse erro "Erro cannot resolve symbol R" no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Importei um projeto feito no *Eclipse* para o *Android Studio* e apareceu erros no no código a respeito do `R` com  a seguinte mensagem

> cannot resolve symbol R

Como corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Geralmente aparece te a opção de quando passas com o Rato por cima fazer alt+enter

Comment: Tente dar um `clean` no seu projeto, observe também se ela foi gerada , se sim deleta ela que ela vai recriar.

Comment: Editei o título para algo mais claro. Sempre especifique o problema no título, isto ajuda outras pessoas a encontrarem a pergunta, lembre-se a sua pergunta **PODE** ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: no meu caso o problema era simples... e bem rídiculo, como disseram acima, o nome de uma das imagens estava diferente do que baixei do meu git... corrigi o nome do arquivo e funcionou.

Comment: Verifique se todas suas imagens não tem letra maiúsculas na nomenclatura, clique em Build, clean project e depois rebuild project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

resolvi assim meu problema

no `Android Studio` foi `file`  e depois em  `Project Structure`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois vá em `app`, no campo **Properties** em **Compile Sdk Version** e **Build Tools Version**  selecione a versão mais recente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Click em OK e pronto o erro some.

Answer (score 5):

Essa não é a raiz do problema.
O `R` é uma classe gerada automaticamente, mas somente quando o projeto não possui nenhum erro que possa impedi-lo de ser gerado.
Vá em `Window -> Show view -> Problems` e veja quais os outros erros que stão acontecendo.
Após solucionar esses outros erros, dê um Clean no projeto para que o `R` seja gerado novamente.

Answer (score 4):

Me deparei frequentemente com esse erro, tente dar "clean" e "rebuild" no projeto.
outras opções são:

"Tools" -> "Android" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Se nenhum dessas soluções atender ao seu erro, entre no processo demorado entretanto necessário de verificar seus arquivos XML e seu AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 2):

Esse problema trata-se de alguma coisa errada dentro da pasta "res", na maioria das vezes, o nome das imagens ou qualquer outra coisa que tem lá não estão de acordo com as regras do compilador, para fazer o teste, recorte tudo que tem lá e coloque em outro lugar e veja se resolveu o problema, caso sim, procure em todos os itens qual é o que está com algum nome não permitido, por exemplo, começando com letra maiuscula, com ifem ou coisa desse tipo.

Answer (score 2):

Se o erro persistir mesmo depois de seguir todas as sugestões a cima, faça o seguinte. Mude o modo de visão de Android  para Project logo você verá algumas pastas desconhecidas e na raiz, (no meu é a primeira pasta) vai ter um .gradle, pode exclui-la e da um clean no projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Turma, a quem não conseguiu resolver seguindo as opções acima, segue o passo que me ajudou a corrigir o problema.

**Clique em Run > Edit Configurations.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida clique na opção **JAR Application** e defina o JRE e o "Search sources ..." conforme a imagem, clique em Ok e em seguida clique em Buil > Clean project e em seguida Make Project. Para mim funcionou corretamente....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]