# Erro no Android Studio - Diversas mensagens do tipo `Cannot resolve the ...`

Tags: android, android-studio

Boa tarde, estou com um erro no Android Studio e não consigo concerta-lo. 
Quando eu abri meu projeto diversas mensagens do tipo  `cannot resolve the symbol` e em vermelho apareceram, como está na imagem. 
Alguém consegue me ajudar, por favor? Como por exemplo a minha MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.8:8080/gms/webresources/usuario/";
private static final Gson g = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(usuario.class, new dec()).create();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    /*List<usuario.usuarioData> list = bd.buscar();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("AQUI" + list.get(i));
    }*/

}

public void entrarSistema(View view) {
    final db_funcao bd = new db_funcao(this);
    usuarioDAO dao = new usuarioDAO();


    final EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
    EditText senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);


    //VERIFICA SE OS EDITTEXT SÃO VAZIOS
    if (login.getText().length() == 0) {

        login.setError("Campo vazio");

    } else {
        if (senha.getText().length() == 0) {
            senha.setError("Campo vazio");
        } else {
            if (senha.getText().length() < 6) {
                senha.setError("Senha incorreta");
            } else {

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(g)).build();
                usuarioService service = retrofit.create(usuarioService.class);
                Call<String> user = service.verificarUsuario(login.getText().toString(), senha.getText().toString());
                user.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                        String resultado = response.body();
                        if (resultado.equals("false")) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Senha ou usuário não existente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        } else { //TOAST LOGIN
                            if (resultado.equals("true")) {
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ACESSO PERMITIDO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                                toast.show();


                                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(g)).build();
                                usuarioService service = retrofit.create(usuarioService.class);
                                retrofit2.Call<List<String>> dados  = service.verificarCargoENome(login.getText().toString());
                                dados.enqueue(new Callback<List<String>>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse
                                        (retrofit2.Call <List<String>> call, Response <List<String>>response)
                                        {
                                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                                                List<usuarios> dados = response.body();


                                                for (usuarios u : users) {
                                                    Log.i("USER", u.getNome());
                                                    Log.i("USER", "----------------------------------------------------------");
                                                }


                                            } else {
                                                Log.i("USER", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                                                Log.i("USER", "----------------------------------------------------------");

                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure
                                        (retrofit2.Call < List < usuarios >> call, Throwable t){
                                            Log.i("USER", t.getMessage());
                                            Log.i("USER", "----------------------------------------------------------");

                                        }
                                    });



                                String nome = bd.verificarUsuario(login.getText().toString());
                                String cargo = bd.verificarCargo(login.getText().toString());


                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuDrawer.class);

                                intent.putExtra("chave1", nome);
                                intent.putExtra("chave2", cargo);


                                startActivity(intent);

                                finish();
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                    }


                });

            }
        }

    }

}


//CHAMA UMA ACTIVITY (TELA)
void recuperarSenha(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, recuperarSenha.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Articuno meu código está todo assim. O objetivo da pergunta não é diretamente ligado ao código. Ou formas de implementação. Ao abrir meu AndroidStudio todo o código do projeto ficou conforme o explicado na pergunta e em Vermelho. Inseri o Código também, mesmo não fazendo sentido por não ser a melhor forma de visualizar o problema.

Comment: Entendi, o problema seria semelhante a este? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70925/28595

Comment: @Articuno seria não. Ele estava normal até eu reiniciar o pc e ficar assim.

Comment: Mas o erro é só isso mesmo? Pelo que pesquisei, geralmente tem algo a mais na mensagem, como no link: `cannot resolve the symbol R`. A mensagem não diz qual o simbolo que não consegue resolver?

Comment: @Articuno sim sim. A cada "marcação" em vermelho como está na imagem, aparece : `cannot resolve the ... `

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema, através dos passos: File > Invalidate Caches/Restart... > Invalidate and Restar

Não sei o que aconteceu, mas deu certo. Muito obrigado.